# При запросах на русском языке suggest yandex выдает ошибки

Tags: php, яндекс-поиск

вообщем ситуация такая, suggest.yandex.ru если сделать запросы на ENG языке то все работает отлично.
Пример запроса **SOS**

А если делать запросы на русском языке, то выдает ошибки.

Пример запроса **ЛЮБОВЬ**

***[http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=ЛЮБОВЬ&v=2](http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=%D0%9B%D0%AE%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AC&v=2)***

Рабочий пример скрипта ниже.

Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему

```
<?php
    $file=file_get_contents("http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=sos&v=2");
    $file=strrchr($file,"[");
    $file=substr($file,0,strpos($file,"]"))."]";
    $file=iconv("CP1251","UTF-8",$file);
    $data=json_decode($file);
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        print '<li>'.$val.'</li>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что они работают в Unicode и русские буквы надо перекодировать.
Вот как твоя ссылка со словом "ЛЮБОВЬ" выглядит на самом деле: http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=%D0%9B%D0%AE%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AC&v=2

```
$word = 'ЛЮБОВЬ';
$file = file_get_contents("http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=" . rawurlencode($word)."&v=2");
```

А вот это вообще не надо делать, потому что они и так уже отвечают в UTF-8:

```
$file=iconv("CP1251","UTF-8",$file);
```

А если последний параметр подставить **v=4**, то ответ идёт сразу в JSON и резать строки не надо:

http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=%D0%9B%D0%AE%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AC&v=4

---

В итоге получилось:

```
<?php
$word="ЛЮБОВЬ";
$file=file_get_contents("http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=".rawurlencode($word)."&v=4");
$data=json_decode($file, true);
list(,$data)=$data;
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    print '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Хм, что-то не понял... А как рабочий код будет выглядить?

Comment: Добавил пример

Comment: Вот что выдает на твой скрипт

Warning: file_get_contents(http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?ct=text/html&part=%CB%DE%C1%CE%C2%DC&v=4) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request in /home/srbcmjnv/public_html/sss/bla.php on line 3



Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/srbcmjnv/public_html/sss/bla.php:3) in /home/srbcmjnv/public_html/sss/bla.php on line 6


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/srbcmjnv/public_html/sss/bla.php on line 7

Comment: http://take.ms/2uW10 нет ошибки, ответ получен и разобран

Comment: Может как-то прикрутить Unicode?

Comment: Sorry, проверил на другом хостинге и все работает хорошо.
Спасибо

Comment: Ещё один момент - я файл то в кодировке UTF-8 создал. Если у тебя win-1251, то надо сначала сделать $word = iconv('win-1251','utf-8','ЛЮВОВЬ');